# What linguistic operation is used in "I declined your report"

Tags: terminology

The OP in this [EL&U question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/41710/3306) says:

> *?I declined your report.*

There is some mutually-understood portion that was dropped from the sentence. In my [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41710/when-to-use-decline-for-polite-refusal-and-when-not-to/41715#41715) (comment section), I contrasted

> Visa declined to permit the credit card transaction.

with

> Visa declined the credit card transaction.

I think that "to permit" is mutually understood.

What is the linguistic operation that allows the drop of the mutually understood portion? I know that if it were a pronoun, the operation would be called a *Pro drop*. (For example, in Italian, one may drop the pronoun "He" in "He speaks" and simply say *parla*, because Italian verbs are inflected with person and gender.)

If the operation were *raising*, I would expect that a complete sentence would be raised, as in

> Visa permitted the transaction.

being raised to

> It seems Visa permitted the transaction.

But the entire sentence cannot be raised, as in

> *Visa declined Visa permitted the transaction.

What is the linguistic operation that allows a mutually-understood deletion from "Visa declined to permit the credit card transaction" to "Visa declined the credit card transaction"?

Bonus: something in that operation would also have to explain why "I declined your report" is less grammatical than "I declined to read/to accept/to indorse your report."

---

Edit: Adding examples of a deleted infinitival.

1. Clenching his chubby, little fists, Bill declined (to eat) the pasta.
2. Wary about unsealed barrel, Bill declined (to accept) the pasta shipment.
3. Since the waiter had his thumb in the entrée, Bill declined (to receive) the pasta.
4. ? Since it had been on the shelf for a year, Bill declined (to ship) the pasta.
5. ? Liking it extra crunchy, Bill declined (to boil) the pasta.

Something about the pragmatics of "decline" seem to force the deleted infinitival to be near "accept" or "permit." In 1, Bill's mommy has a yummy spoon of pasta coming his way, but he will not accept. In 3, Bill is not permitting a plate of cooked pasta to be set on his restaurant table. In 4 and 5, the sentences may be grammatical with the parenthetical statements but are ungrammatical without. That is to say, "Bill declined to ship the pasta," but "? Bill declined the pasta," even though 1 and 3 are "Bill declined the pasta."

Comment: I corrected the italian verb "parla" because parlo is the first person, not the third. :)

Comment: Thank you, Alenanno. I left "If the operation were raising" instead of your edit "If the operation was raising," because I am holding on to the arcane notion that the subjunctive mood still exists in English.

Comment: Ah ok... I thought that "If I were you" was the only case... :)

Comment: I disagree that "Visa declined the credit card transaction" is dropping anything. "Visa declined to permit the credit card transaction" seems highly awkward to me.

Comment: @James Tauber, OK, I will edit and add some other examples that will, I hope, be less awkward.

Comment: I'm still not understanding the phenomenon you are trying to capture. I find 'decline' taking an infinitive to be awkward in all cases and would use something like 'refuse'. Perhaps a dialect difference?

Comment: @James: It seems the use of "decline to + infinitve" peaked in the 1880s and has been on a steady decline ever since (pun unintended). But it's still not rare, [here are some google hits for instance](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22declined%20to%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en).

Comment: @hippietrail yeah, as I suggested, it might be a dialect issue (I'm Australian).

Comment: @James: I'm Australian too (-: I'd say it's a bit formal, you don't hear it every day.

Comment: I'm from the U.S. and I do have the _decline to + infinitive_ construction in my dialect, but none of the examples you provided work for me as interchangeable; I think the reason is that the sense of _decline_ without the infinitive is that of "reject" whereas _decline to X_ means "politely denied consent to X" (as in _declined to speak_). So, _declined to accept X_ sounds redundant to me and would not be synonymous with _declined X_; rather, it would only be marginally felicitous in a situation with three parties: _Lena wanted Mo to accept Alma's invitation, but Mo declined to accept it._

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think that there is any deletion going on.  The word *decline* in English simply has two possible uses – one followed by an infinitive, one followed by a noun phrase object.  This is similar to "want":

```
(1) I want to go to the park
(2) I want an apple
```

The infinitive-taking version is a control verb (as opposed to a raising verb, which you discuss in your question).  [This online syntax book](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/syntax-textbook/ch9.html#sc) (direct link to relevant section) has an overview of control structures, diagnostics, and the differences between control and raising.